# Conditional Formatting Based on Multiple Rules

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a multi rule custom formula for conditional formatting purposes in Google Sheets.

Here is what I want to achieve  -

If Deal Size is Small, the deal length cell should be highlighted a specific color based on the criteria -

- 0-35 Green
- 35-40 Yellow
- 40+ Red

If Deal Size is Large, the deal length cell should be highlighted a specific color based on the criteria -

- 0-45 Green
- 45-55 Yellow
- 55+ Red

Here is some sample data -

| Date Deal Started | Date Deal Ended | Deal Length | Deal Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/13/2023 | 1/25/2023 | 12 | Small |
| 12/8/2022 | 1/17/2023 | 40 | Large |
| 11/8/2022 | 1/9/2023 | 62 | Small |
| 10/7/2022 | 1/31/2023 | 116 | Large |
| 12/12/2022 | 1/30/2023 | 49 | Large |

I've read some blogs online but haven’t found a solution for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0-35 for green and 35-40 for yellow. So what color if exactly 35?

Use 3 custom formulas for conditional formatting. Move = signs where needed. Range in example `C2:C7`

Green:

```
=OR(AND(D2="Small",C2>0,C2<35),AND(D2="Large",C2>0,C2<45))
```

Yellow:

```
=OR(AND(D2="Small",C2>=35,C2<40),AND(D2="Large",C2>=45,C2<55))
```

Red:

```
=OR(AND(D2="Small",C2>=40),AND(D2="Large",C2>=55))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One follow-up, what would the formulas be if I wanted to have the same color conditions but calculate the difference of the Date Deal Start from Today if some don't have a Date Deal Ended yet?

Comment: Not ended means is empty? In this case you need to check if B is empty, if not, use nest formula written above, if empty, then replace C2 in formula to TODAY()-A2. Something like for =if(B2="",(OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<35),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<45))),(OR(AND(D2="Small",C2>0,C2<35),AND(D2="Large",C2>0,C2<45)))) for green. There is a shorter way to do it, but I use formula from my answer

Comment: Would the formula be simplified if the ones with empty cells are on a separate sheet?

Currently, we have it set up where the deals that are still in progress are on one sheet and the ones that have closed are on another.

Comment: Then just replace C2 in formulas to (TODAY()-A2). For example =OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<35),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<45))

Comment: These are the formulas I added based on that recent one in order green, yellow, red, and the formatting was off on my side. Couldn't share a screenshot - 

=OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<35),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>0,(TODAY()-A2)<45))

=OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>36,(TODAY()-A2)<40),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>46,(TODAY()-A2)<55))

=OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>=41),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>=56))

Comment: These are formulas for sheet where project still not ended. These looks fine. Add helper column with =TODAY()-A2 and drag down to see what day difference you get and if conditions are met

Comment: I made a test Google Sheet and some colors aren't appearing - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICHy6Uku5lqKWE6uRHcYQn-eqjlFfbJ2AQ1FDJERZvI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well it appears where you selected range correctly. You had different ranges, for one color starting from A1 for other from A2, it messed up formatting

Comment: I see, but I'm seeing that cell A6 doesn’t have a color appearing

Comment: Because your rules are >=56 (56 or more) and <55 (less than 55), so no formatting for 55

Comment: That makes sense, appreciate you pointing out that error. I guess my last question is if the cells in column A are blank but some of the other cells are filled, what would be the formula I can make sure the cell is clear instead of filled? Cell A7 is an example.

Comment: If A7 is empty, then TODAY()-A7=TODAY(). And dates are integers starting with 1 from 1900 01 01. Wrap everything in additional AND with checking if A7 is empty (=AND(A2<>"",OR(AND(D2="Small",(TODAY()-A2)>=41),AND(D2="Large",(TODAY()-A2)>=56))))  or leave D column blank (updated your example with checking if not empty)

Answer (score 0):

or you can do it like this too:

green:

```
=((D2="Small")*(C2>0)*(C2<35))+((D2="Large")*(C2>0)*(C2<45))
```

yellow:

```
=((D2="Small")*(C2>=35)*(C2<40))+((D2="Large")*(C2>=45)*(C2<55))
```

red:

```
=((D2="Small")*(C2>=40))+((D2="Large")*(C2>=55))
```